# How to find out number of installments between two dates?

Tags: c#

Suppose a Bank-Customer pays RD installments at every last day of the month.

So there must be 2 installments between the dates 12th October, 2013 and 10th December, 2013.

How can I find out how many installments the customer paid during this period of tine?

Should I use [NodaTime library](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)?

Ok. Here is my effort:

```
public sealed class DateDifference
{
    int years;

    public int Years
    {
        get { return years; }
    }
    int months;

    public int Months
    {
        get { return months; }
    }
    int days;

    public int Days
    {
        get { return days; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[DateDifference Years={0}, Months={1}, Days={2}]", years, months, days);
    }


    public DateDifference(DateTime earlier, DateTime later)
    {
        if (later < earlier)
            throw new ArgumentException("later is earlier than 'earlier'.");
        bool isleapday = (earlier.Month == 2 && earlier.Day == 29);
        DateTime tmp = isleapday ? new DateTime(earlier.Year, 2, 28) : earlier;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                tmp = tmp.AddYears(1);
                if (isleapday && DateTime.IsLeapYear(tmp.Year))
                    tmp = new DateTime(tmp.Year, 2, 29);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (tmp <= later)
            {
                years++;
                earlier = tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        // Add months
        tmp = earlier;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                tmp = tmp.AddMonths(1);
                if (isleapday && tmp.Day != 29 && tmp.Month != 2)
                    tmp = new DateTime(tmp.Year, tmp.Month, 29);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (tmp <= later)
            {
                months++;
                earlier = tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        tmp = earlier;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                tmp = tmp.AddDays(1);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (tmp <= later)
            {
                days++;
                earlier = tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

DateDifference dateDifference = new DateDifference(startDateTextBox.Value, endDateTextBox.Value);

            this.noOfInstallmentsTextBox.Text =  ((int)++dateDifference.Months).ToString();
```

Comment: You should probably show some effort first. Get the installments the customer paid, limit that to the installments between these two dates and get the `Count` property.

Comment: @BROY : first Please show us what you have Done. so that we can help you easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll start off by saying I'm not prioritizing speed here.  Datetime issues are tricky.  Writing methods that you can be sure will work in all sorts of corner cases all over the world is *hard*.  This approach is designed to work despite all edge cases and for that to be clear to the reader.  It does not attempt to make cleaver optimizations because the tend to not work in odd edge cases, which are simply too common to ignore in the datetime world.

So first off we'll start with a simple helper method to get all of the days between two dates:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Days(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    DateTime current = start;
    while (current < end)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

(If you want something more general purpose here you might get the next date after `start`, if you want all returned values to be "midnight".  You might also swap `start` and `end` if they are in the reverse order, or throw an exception, etc.  Also consider the exact semantics that you want; I have the bounds inclusive on start and exclusive on end, you may want it entirely inclusive, entirely exclusive, etc.)

We'll also create a method to determine if a date is the last day of the month.

```
public static bool IsLastDayOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    return date.AddDays(1).Month != date.Month;
}
```

We can actually *define* the last day of the month as being the only date for which its month is different from the following day's month.

Now when we combine these together we have an implementation that is very simple and clear to the reader:

```
public static int InstallmentCount(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return Days(start, end)
        .Where(day => IsLastDayOfMonth(day))
        .Count();
}
```

Comment: The last day of the month was an analogy. The routine must work for any day of the month.

Comment: @BROY Then all you need to do is change "IsLastDayOfMonth" to whatever logic you have for determining if this is the given day in question.  If you want to know if it's the first day of the month, compare `date.Day` to one, or 15, or whatever other day you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you.

```
int foo(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    int count = end.Month - start.Month;
    if (count < 0)
        count += 12;
    count += 12 * (end.Year - start.Year);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Need a special check to see whether the `end` is the last day of the month (would be +1 then, if the OP wants it inclusive)

Comment: What if `start` and `end` aren't set to the same time zone, or the same calendar?

Comment: daniel, i'm not certain that captures the nuance of lastday of month, when measuring the dates. this code would give two installments if the start date was 01-Jan-2013 and the end date was 01-Feb-2013

Comment: Reed Copsey, I suggest, that payment transaction submitted only after this day:)

Comment: Yeah, I did not think about time zone.

Comment: I really think this is where [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) comes to mind. Start off by writing a set of (unit) tests, which provides a few examples of valid start/end dates, and what they should return. Then you can quite easily work out the algorithm.

Comment: test-driven development is perfect, but if you don't have requirement with time zone in this case it will not help you, in all other cases it works correct.

Comment: Good point. I think the OP could clarify whether the solution needs to support this or not.